# Getting TextBox's Text on Next Page if Visible is false (Cross-Page Postback)

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page that contains two tables (each with some textbox controls in it).

When page is first rendered, only the first table is shown (second table's `Visible` property is set to `false`).  User fills out the textboxes and clicks a continue button.

Now, the first table's `Visible = false;` and second table's `Visible = true;` and user fills out the second table.

Submit button is clicked. `PostBackURL` of this button is set to a new page in which I'm trying to get and display what was just entered in the last page using `Request.Form["ctrlname"];`

The problem is... The first table's visibility was set to false so server never rendered it.  But shouldn't its data still be in VIEWSTATE?  How could I retrieve the data from the first table that was not rendered?

Obviously I cant use `Request.Form["table1ctrlname"];` to get data from a textbox in table1, but isn't there a way of querying the incoming VIEWSTATE directly to get this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PreviousPage` property on your next Page.

Example:

Page-1 (ASPX):

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
    First Text Box:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="pnl2" runat="server" Visible="false">
    Second Text Box:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" OnClick="btnNext_Click" Text="Next" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" PostBackUrl="~/Page2.aspx" />
```

Page-1 (Code):

```
protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.pnl1.Visible = false;
    this.pnl2.Visible = true;
}
```

Page-2 (Code):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsPostBack)
    {
        var sValue1 = ((TextBox)this.PreviousPage.FindControl("txt1")).Text;
        var sValue2 = ((TextBox)this.PreviousPage.FindControl("txt2")).Text;
        Console.WriteLine(sValue1);
        Console.WriteLine(sValue2);
    }
}
```

For details, see [Cross-Page Posting in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)